# Browser downloads video stream instead of playing it

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, ffserver

I'm trying to stream video from IP camera to browser using `ffmpeg` and `ffserver` but if I try to open stream in any browser it starts downloading it instead of playing. I've tried to display video using `<video>`  tag but that doesn't work either: Here is the code I used:

```
 <video width="800" height="600" controls>
        <source src="http://10.10.7.19:8090/cam4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

The stream works fine in vlc, it is H.264 stream. ffserver shows buffer underflow errors when I try to view it in chrome.
When I try to open it in firefox I get `No video with supported format and MIME type found` error on video element.

How do I make it work? Also, are there any tools for debugging video streams on Chrome or Firefox (console doesn't show any errors) ?

Comment: Please do not ask two questions in the same post.  Debug tool: https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/media-internals

Answer (score 0):

The server must set the correct Content-Type header.